# .NET Interoperability Issue

Tags: sockets

First of all, this is a follow-up question to [Should I use WCF or raw sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325847/should-i-use-wcf-or-raw-sockets). Thanks to everyone who responded, it helped me a lot!

Lately, a few of my requirements changed. The **main** hurdle that came up is that I now have to support Linux clients in addition to Windows. I have to use .NET at server side as a requirement. I also need to maintain persistent connections with clients (or poll). I would like to request feedback from the community on the following options:

1. Use a simpler version of pub-sub model. I have a web service at the server which the clients constantly poll (I prepackage the scripts/binaries that I need to run at the client and issue commands from the server via the service). The server puts the tasks for clients in a queue, and the clients pick it up. This model becomes highly interoperable, as I can write the client in any platform. Also, I don't have to worry about firewalls at client side because of http. However, I am concerned about the polling (I might have to poll every few seconds, for 1000s of clients). I read about Comet, but unfortunately, it seems like a lot of effort to implement it in C#.
2. Use normal sockets, create a persistent connection from clients and use those pipes. Here, I'm concerned about persistent connections (I need them to control the client, they are behind NATs). Normally, I've seen people creating a thread for each connection, which I believe is not scalable. Am I correct? Is asynchronous calls/socket selects a better way to go?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard sockets to communicate will be portable among different OSs.  Plain tcp sockets are a very mature technology.  You could also use web services (http), those sit on top of sockets.  Web services are more practical when going across the internet (firewall issues etc).

Comment: Thanks seand, I decided to go with plain TCP sockets!